# How to disable half rounding in mysql decimal field?

Tags: mysql, decimal, rounding

How to store 1493240911.312 when I put 1493240911.3126XX..
My field is Decimal 13,3 and it stores 1493240911.313 when i put 1493240911.3126XX or 1493240911.311 when I put 1493240911.3124XX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a value is stored in a field with fewer decimal places than the input, it's always rounded to the nearest value of the specified precision, so `.3124` is rounded to `.312` and `.3126` is rounded to `.313`. If you want to round down instead of to the nearer value, you need to do this before storing the value into the field. Use:

```
FLOOR(newvalue * 1000)/1000
```

Comment: I need no rounding at all, just three fixed numbers after point

Comment: That's what rounding down is.

Comment: Question more about how to store it with just cut anything after three numbers after point, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Doesn't this do what you want? When you multiply by 1000 and get the floor, that discards anything after the 3rd decimal place.

Comment: i meant without additional operations :)

Comment: There's no built-in way to do it. That's what I explained in the first line of my answer. You either have to modify the original string to remove the extra characters, or you process the value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change your Decimal to be `Decimal 13,4` and handle the rounding yourself.